# Generic Function: Type that isn't of expected Type

Tags: dart

I got stuck with a compiler error that I could narrow down to this little snippet

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

B b;

void testB(B b) {}
void callIt<T extends A>(T param, void func(T)) => func(param);
void main() {
  callIt(b, testB);
}
```

It refuses to compile with
`error: The function 'testB' has type 'void Function(B)' that isn't of expected type 'void Function(dynamic)'. This means its parameter or return type does not match what is expected. (strong_mode_invalid_cast_function at [pavement] lib\main.dart:13)`

Same error with

```
  callIt<B>(b, testB);
```

I can work around it with

```
    void testB(b) {}
```

But I would really love to keep the param type there.
Please, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to your `func` notation. I do not know where you got that from, but here is working notation:

```dart
ReturnType Function(ParameterType parameterName) functionName
```

Applying this to your example, your function should look like this (I added braces for readability):

```dart
void callIt<T extends A>(T param, void Function(T t) func) {
  func(param);
}
```

In the [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#keywords), you can see that `Function` is a keyword in Dart.

Comment: Why would we need to provide the param name there? The standard does not make sense here.